# How to plot an nmds with coloured/symbol points based on SIMPROF

Tags: r, cluster-computing, vegan, hclust, mds

Hi so i am trying to plot my nmds of a assemblage data which is in a bray-curtis dissimilarity matrix in R. I have been able to apply ordielipse(),ordihull() and even change the colours based on group factors created by cutree() of a hclst()

e.g using the dune data from the vegan package

```
data(dune)
Dune.dis <- vegdist(Dune, method = "bray)
Dune.mds <- metaMDS(Dune, distance = "bray", k=2)

#hierarchical cluster
clua <- hclust(Dune.dis, "average")
plot(clua, hang = -1)
# set groupings
rect.hclust(clua, 4)
grp <- cutree(clua, 4)

#plot mds
plot(Dune.mds, display = "sites", type = "text", cex = 1.5)

#show groupings
ordielipse(Dune.mds, group = grp, border =1, col ="red", lwd = 3)
```

or even colour the points just by the cutree

```
colvec <- c("red2", "cyan", "deeppink3", "green3")
colvec[grp]
plot(Dune.mds, display = "sites", type = "text", cex = 1.5) #or use type = "points"
points(P4.mds, col = colvec[c2], bg =colvec[c2], pch=21)
```

However what i really want to do is use the SIMPROF function using the package "clustsig" to then colour the points based on significant groupings - this is more of a technical coding language thing - i am sure there is a way to create a string of factors but i  am sure there is a more efficient way to do it

heres my code so far for that:

```
simp <- simprof(Dune.dis, num.expected = 1000, num.simulated = 999, method.cluster = "average", method.distance = "braycurtis", alpha = 0.05, sample.orientation = "row")
#plot dendrogram    
simprof.plot(simp, plot = TRUE)
```

Now i am just not sure how do the next step to plot the nmds using the groupings defined by the SIMPROF - how do i make the SIMPROF results a factor string without literally typing it my self it myself?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wrote you know how to get colours from an `hclust` object with `cutree`. Then read the documentation of `clustsig::simprof`. This says that `simprof` returns an `hclust` object within its result object. It also returns `numgroups` which is the suggested number of clusters. Now you have all information you need to use the `cutree` of `hclust` you already know. If your `simprof` result is called `simp`, use `cutree(simp$hclust, simp$numgroups)` to extract the integer vector corresponding to the `clustsig::simprof` result, and use this to colours.

I have never used `simprof` or **clustsig**, but I gathered all this information from its documentation.

Comment: Thank you very much! I got that to work easily - very clear response! I am still working on my coding and understanding the R package documentation - but I still have a way to go yet, so thank you for your help.